# How to get the position of a gui in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a second gui when I click a button and am then destroying my original gui.

I would like to create this new gui in the same position as the original gui.

Is there a function that will let me get the geometry or position of the original gui before I destroy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [geometry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) method of any root or toplevel window. It will return a string of the form "widthxheight+x+y".